# Why does Google Drive show this error?

Tags: google-drive

"Sorry, you can't view or download this file at this time.

Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently. Please try accessing the file again later. If the file you are trying to access is particularly large or is shared with many people, it may take up to 24 hours to be able to view or download the file. If you still can't access a file after 24 hours, contact your domain administrator."

Why does google docs/drive show this error. I am downloading a file Windows ADK for windows 8 [WADK8-EN.iso](https://docs.google.com/folderview?id=0B4wdLVE4C3K8My1GaC1vSXJMWG8)

through IDM and after some time 30-40 mins the file stops downloading and cannot be resumed. If I refresh the link and try to download I get this sorry error and cannot download the file before some 10-15 hours. It's kind of bullshit that a file 2-3 gb cannot be downloaded although it wouldn't take me more than 4-5 hours.

Also I found a tut to bypass the error on [here](http://mathematechnology.blogspot.in/2013/10/solved-google-drivedocs-sorry-you-cant.html) and it seems the file is downloadable but not resumable with the previously downloaded file and still this file too stops after some time and refuses to resume before some hours. I think the ISP is responsible but I have downloaded bigger files from other websites and huge files but they download perfectly. Are google drive people mad or something. Is ther any way to download the file without any stops further or do I have to waste 3-4 days on downloading this puny file.

Comment: Though you may have a legitimate technical issue here, it is not one to get upset about, nor is SuperUser a soapbox for your complaints. Please consider not taking this issue personally, gather yourself, and approach this with a technical mindset.

Answer (score 1):

Seems file may be bigger than maximum allowed for download:

[image: WA59649 example]

with [The maximum download file size is 2 GB.](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423534?hl=en&ref_topic=2375187).

But [You can run the Windows ADK Setup program directly from the Internet by using either the graphical user interface (GUI) or the command line.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en).

Comment: Dude I wanted an iso. Although I have downloaded the file now, 5 days after this post. So I might be thinking if there is a backdraw to this, kindly answer.

Comment: Actually I download many files from Google Drive and this was the first time I had to download a 2.56 GB file from GD as the file was not available anywhere. Sometimes a file is only posted on GD and so if I ever run into this problem again, do you have a solution to it. Like a backdoor to a website?